# Link to a different URL after fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

It is on a submit page. User presses the Submit button.
If the request is succeed, it will go to product page. If not, it stays on the current submit page.

```
handleSubmit() {
    fetch(post request)
    .then(response => return response)
    .then(submit => 
        if (submit.ok === true) {
            <Link to={"/product" />
        } else {
            this.setState({error: Submit failed});
        })
     .catch()
}

render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    )
}
```

It isn't directing to another page or Product page. Am I missing anything?

Currently it isn't change the URL, it just added the path on the current path.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct usage of `<Link>`.

To programmatically go to another route, you can do:

```
this.props.history.push("/newRoute");
```

assuming you're passing the `history` object using either `withRouter` or by having the current component within a `Switch` statement for example.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { b: false };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/horse");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const RoutedApp = withRouter(App);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <RoutedApp />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yqx6315k09).